# Does a payment receiver get a full name of a cardholder when I pay with a credit card?

Tags: credit-card, debit-card, privacy

What information about a cardholder does a payment receiver get when paid with credit card via direct transfer. Examples: Spotify, Netflix, etc... How's all buying digital goods process released?

Comment: Are you entering your card details onto the spotify site, or are you entering the spotify details on the credit card site?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://www.aclu.org/blog/privacy-technology/consumer-privacy/why-dont-we-have-more-privacy-when-we-use-credit-card

Comment: What does "get when paid with credit card via direct transfer" mean? Are you filling the credit card details on their website? If so, you're also filling the cardholder name on the same form. Also, privacy laws are very jurisdiction specific, answers will vary depending on where you are.